# Trying to over work come wallabg root requirement using subdomain

Tags: nginx

- Have stage.leaves.anant.us main domain and admin.stage.leaves.anant.us subdomain.
- Since wallabag expects to be in root folder working on work around by creating sub-domain. '/' is already used by other application.
- Info : Able to get required page properly using admin.stage.leaves.anant.us. However getting 'topic' page when accessed like stage.leaves.anant.us/admin/. Would you please advise what i am missing.

Below is nginx configuration"

```
    upstream docker-wallabag {
        server wallabag:80;
    }

    upstream topic {
        server topic:1000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name stage.leaves.anant.us;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://topic/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /admin/ {
            proxy_pass         http://admin.stage.leaves.anant.us/;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  admin.stage.leaves.anant.us;
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-wallabag/;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }}
```

Comment: In `location /admin/` try to change `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to `proxy_set_header Host admin.stage.leaves.anant.us;`

Comment: It is working. However It redirects.